# Script to remove spaces in all files and folders?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script which removes spaces in a single folder/file name. I want to make it work so that it removes all spaces in folder/files name in the directory the script exists.

**MY Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(ls | grep " ")

test=$(echo $var | sed 's/ //')

mv "$var" $test
```

How it worked
[image]

[image]

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Simply use `rename`!!  `rename 's/ //g' *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ls | grep " " | while read file_name
do 
    mv "$file_name" "$(echo $file_name | sed -E 's/ +//g')"
done
```

`sed -E` is so that you can use some simple regex, and `/ +/` so it can work in case of multiple consecutive spaces such as    . And `/g` so it replaces every occurrences such as `foo  baa   .txt` .

Comment: For a beginners script this would be ok-ish. But it is not a good idea to pares the output of `ls`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Ok I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
for f in * ; do
    if [[ "$f" =~ \  ]] ; then
        mv "$f" "${f// /_}"
    fi
done
```

Explanattion:

```
for f in * ; do
```

loops over all file names in the directory. It doesn't have the quirks of `ls` that make parsing the output of `ls` a bad idea.

```
if [[ "$f" =~ \  ]] ; then
```

This is the `bash` way of pattern matching. The `\`  is the pattern. You need to escape the space with a backslash, otherwise the shell will not recognize it as a pattern.

```
        mv "$f" "${f// /_}"
```

`${f// /_}` is the `bash` way of pattern-substitution. The `//` means replace all occurrences. The syntax is `${variable//pattern/replacement}` to replace all patterns in the variable with the replacement.